# Filter rows based on regex pattern and ID

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I have a `df` like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = c("A", "A", "B", NA, "A", "B", "B", "B"),
  speech = c("hi", "how are you [Larry]?", "[uh]", "(0.123)", "I'm fine [you 'n Mary] how's it [goin]?", "[erm]", "(0.4)", "well")
)
```

I want to filter out those rows (1) where `speech` is made up entirely of an expression wrapped in square brackets `[...]` from string start to string end AND (2) those rows by the same `ID` which **follow** the row where `[...]` makes up the whole `speech`. I know how to filter out the rows with `[...]`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(grp = rleid(id)) %>%
  filter(grepl("^\\[.*?\\]$", speech))
```

but I don't know how to also filter out the same-`ID` rows that follow the `[...]` row. The **desired output** is this:

```
df
  id speech
1  B   [uh]
2  B  [erm]
3  B  (0.4)
4  B   well
```

Comment: 'hi' is not in `[...]`and does not follow from a same-`ID` `speech` whose first element is `[...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the grouping index with `rleid` asin the OP's code, then `filter` out groups that doesn't have a `[` in the `first` element of 'speech', `ungroup`

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
    group_by(grp = rleid(id)) %>% 
    filter(str_detect(first(speech), "^\\[")) %>% 
    ungroup  %>%
    select(-grp)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  id    speech
#  <chr> <chr> 
#1 B     [uh]  
#2 B     [erm] 
#3 B     (0.4) 
#4 B     well
```

EDIT: Based on @ChrisRuehlemann's comments

Comment: It seems that `df %>% 
  group_by(grp = rleid(id)) %>% 
  filter(str_detect(first(speech), "^\\["))` already does the job!

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann But that returns only row for 'A' as well which you don't want

Comment: No. Note the added `^`to the pattern.

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann yes, you are right.  I was thinking about extracting the `(` as well separately